# ColorPicker without color square in Javafx?

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I want to implement my own SplitMenu ColorPicker that actually functions like a SplitMenuButton. To do this, I have a button which when clicked changes the color of selected text to the current color, and a color picker, which does the same, but also changes the current color. So my FXML looks like this:

```
<HBox>
    <Button text="Aa" fx:id="colorTextButton" styleClass="leftButton" onAction="#colorText"/>
    <ColorPicker fx:id="colorPicker" styleClass="rightButton colorPicker" onAction="#setColor">
</HBox>
```

my CSS looks like this:

```
.leftButton {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0.25em 0 0 0.25em;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: #bcbcbc;
    -fx-border-width: 0.08em 0.00em 0.08em 0.08em;
    -fx-border-radius: 0.25em 0 0 0.25em;
}

.rightButton {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: #bcbcbc;
    -fx-border-width: 0.08em 0.08em 0.08em 0.04em;
    -fx-border-radius: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
}

.colorPicker {
    -fx-color-label-visible: false;
}
```

Is there any way, either programatically through java or in CSS or FXML to get rid of the square of color in the color picker? It's fairly easy to recreate a similar square as a graphic on my other button, but how do I get rid of the one on the colorpicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the preview color box from ColorPicker using the CSS below :

```
.color-picker > .color-picker-label > .picker-color > .picker-color-rect {
    -fx-stroke: null;
    -fx-fill : null;   
}
```

This will cause the box to disappear completely.

Edit : But as I can see the box will appear again if you open the color palette and keep changing between colors having the mouse(left/right) pressed and it will disappear again when the mouse is released. I will give it a look later or tomorrow.

Edit 2 : Another good way which is better that the above is to hide the Rectangle programatically using the code below :

```
Rectangle rec = (Rectangle) colorPicker.lookup("Rectangle");
rec.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this! I'm probably going to wait until tomorrow or monday to accept this answer, so the question gets seen and hopefully you get some upvotes.

Comment: @MMAdams i would suggest to follow the Edit 2 which is far better solution in case you did not check the edit.

Comment: I tried Edit 2, but `colorPicker.lookup("Rectangle")` always returned null for me, and in any case, I had a css file I was already using to style some buttons and things, so the css answer was easy enough to implement.

Comment: This is very late but for anyone needing to use edit 2, you have to use it after primaryStage.show();.