# How do I hide the secondary colors at the bottom of the ColorPicker pop-up

Tags: javafx

How do I hide the secondary colors at the bottom of the ColorPicker pop-up.

I have consulted the JavaFX CSS documentation, but I cannot resolve it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [ColorPicker without color square in Javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299420/colorpicker-without-color-square-in-javafx)

Comment: @Abra Hide the color in the red circle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you observe the scenegraph of the color picker in below picture: you are interested in only the first GridPane..

[image]

You need to turn off the visibility of all the other unwanted nodes. As the nodes are residing in a VBox, turning off the visibility alone is not sufficient. The spacing will still show, so you need to turn off the managed property of the nodes as well (to skip the layout computing).

To do that, you can include the below css styling in your CSS file.

```
.color-palette > #ColorCustomizerColorGrid,
.color-palette > .label,
.color-palette > .separator,
.color-palette > .hyperlink{
    visibility: hidden;
    -fx-managed: false;
}
```

After adding the above changes, the color picker behaves as below:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

If you are using a javafx version in which `-fx-managed` is not implemented, you can try the below approach of manually turning off the required nodes visibility & managed properties.

But for this, you need to create a custom skin to access the popup content. You don't need any CSS changes in this approach.

```
ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(Color.RED) {
    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new ColorPickerSkin(this) {
            List<String> styles = List.of("label", "separator", "hyperlink");

            @Override
            public void show() {
                // Turn off the visibility of required nodes before showing
                ((Region) getPopupContent().lookup(".color-palette")).getChildrenUnmodifiable().forEach(node -> {
                    if ("ColorCustomizerColorGrid".equals(node.getId()) || node.getStyleClass().stream().anyMatch(styles::contains)) {
                        node.setVisible(false);
                        node.setManaged(false);
                    }
                });
                super.show();
            }
        };
    }
};
```

*Note: You can create separate classes for control and skin if you want to implement this in multiple places*

Comment: The "-fx-managed: false"  does not take effect

Comment: I'm using javafx17